# A JavaScript function is repeated many times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two function print and callPrint bellow. I click call function print the first time is right.
But when click call function print the second or third then function callPrint will be call 2 times or 3 times. 
I have debug on attack file.

```
function print(url) {
    console.log('print');
    var _this = this, iframeId = 'iframeprint', $iframe = $('iframe#iframeprint');
    if ($iframe.attr('src') != url) {
        $.when(
            $iframe.attr('src', 'about:blank'),
            $iframe.load(function () {
                console.log($iframe.prop('contentWindow').document.readyState);
            })
        ).done(function () {
            $iframe.attr('src', url);
            $iframe.load(function () {
                console.log('new');
                _this.callPrint(iframeId);
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.log('old');
        _this.callPrint(iframeId);
    }
}

// initiates print once content has been loaded into iframe
function callPrint(iframeId) {
    console.log('callPrint');
    $('div.wait').hide();
    var PDF = document.getElementById(iframeId);
    PDF.focus();
    PDF.contentWindow.print();
    return false;
}
```

[A JavaScript function is repeated many times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEm10.png)

Comment: The problem is because you're attaching a new `load()` event to the `iframe` handler every time `print()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you're attaching two new `load()` event handlers to the `iframe` every time `print()` is called. To fix this, add a single `load()` event handler and call your function from in there. This will be triggered whenever you update the `src` attribute on the element. Try this:

```
var $iframe = $('#iframeprint').load(function() {
  // You'll need to make sure the function is in scope of the handler
  // There's not enough information in the OP for me to show you how
  callPrint('iframeprint'); 
});

function print(url) {
  var _this = this;

  if ($iframe.attr('src') != url) {
    $iframe.attr('src', url);
  } else {
    _this.callPrint(iframeId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks "Rory McCrossan". I add setTimeout function when callPrint so dialog print will open. But I can't vote for you at the moment.

```
var $iframe = $('iframe#iframeprint').load(function () {
    // You'll need to make sure the function is in scope of the handler
    // There's not enough information in the OP for me to show you how
    setTimeout(function () {
        callPrint('iframeprint');
    }, 100);
});
function print(url) {
    if ($iframe.attr('src') != url) {
        $iframe.attr('src', url);
    } else {
        console.log('old');
        callPrint('iframeprint');
    }
}

// initiates print once content has been loaded into iframe
function callPrint(iframeId) {
    $('div.wait').hide();
    var PDF = document.getElementById(iframeId);
    PDF.focus();
    PDF.contentWindow.print();
}
```